# Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, podfile

I want to config Firebase Firestore. I followed all the steps, but at the last step, I got the error link below I mention.

After Executing this **pod install** command below error I got

> [!] Automatically assigning platform `ios` with version `11.4` on
> target `testing_gowtham` because no platform was specified. Please
> specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See
> `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

My podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'testing_gowtham' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!


  # Pods for testing_gowtham

  target 'testing_gowthamTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'testing_gowthamUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
end
```

I saw this https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform but I did not find which line I need to change .

How to solve this issue?

Comment: See the comment on the first line, it says uncomment second line in order to set the platform.

Comment: I removed second line still same error sir

Comment: Don't remove it, uncomment it

Comment: // # platform :ios, '9.0'   i uncomment like this..but still same error sir

Comment: platform :ios, '9.0'

Comment: Cange the " # platform :ios, '9.0' " To " platform :ios, '9.0' ".
Just remove that "#"

Comment: I am remove # but still same error

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Replace your whole pod file text with below text and then check.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project

# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'testing_gowtham' do

use_frameworks!


pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
end
```

**(or) solution 2**

> `platform :ios, '9.0'` is working...I simply removed **#** this

Comment: thanks for your quick response...just I need to remove this line **# platform :ios, '9.0'** I am right

Comment: No,, let me change my answer

Comment: Thanks bro.. I removed that line same error....can you please give exact answer what should I change..

Comment: Thank you I will check please just a min

Comment: aBilal17 what will the problem sir any another idea

Comment: Bro i have removed another line from my answer. Can you please check it again? or send me your pod file on my email algaffaru@gmail.com

Comment: platform :ios, '9.0' is working bro...I have to remove `#` this

Comment: I am remove # but still same error

Answer (score 17):

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'testing_gowtham' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for testing_gowtham
 pod 'Firebase/Core'
 pod 'Firebase/Firestore'

end
```

Comment: It is a good practice in Stack Overflow community to provide some explanations and comments about what your coding is doing. Please add some description!

Answer (score 14):

In your Podfile ->
Uncomment platform and set ios : 10.0

```
    platform :ios, '10.0'
```

this will work.

Comment: Afterwards, you have to go into the `ios` folder and run `pod repo update` but yes. This does indeed works. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

If the above error occurs when you install `pod 'PusherSwift'` and  `pod 'AlamofireImage'` you have to remove `#` symbol from

```
# platform :ios, '9.0'.
```

Then write the command **pod install** in your **terminal**.

When you run the project again the error will appear according to `'pusher swift'`.you have to click unblock option. Then the problem is successfully solved.

Comment: Great kurupareshan .!! You saved my Time.

Answer (score 8):

**Updated answer for 2022.**
This is due to your minimum deployment target being less than iOS 10. According to the [Firebase ios setup documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup), your project must target ios platform versions iOS 10 or later:

1. command `$ flutter clean`
2. open the Podfile in the directory `ios/Podfile`
3. uncomment the line `platform :ios, '9.0' and change 9.0 to 10.0`

   ```
   # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
     platform :ios, '10.0'
   ```
4. save the file
5. `$ flutter run`

Answer (score 6):

Delete `Podfile.lock` file and run `pod install`.

I got this issue by changing the target iOS version and developing application on more devices.

Worked for me, but be careful - it will replace all, let's say, locked (cached) versions of libraries, that you are using. Check yourself that you fully understand what `Podfile.lock` file does here --> https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html

Answer (score 5):

For **Apple Silicon M1 chips**:

1. Edit ./ios/Podfile
   `platform :ios, '11.4'` or whatever version
2. Install ffi `arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi`
3. Reinstall pods

```
flutter clean
cd ios
arch -x86_64 pod install
cd ..
flutter run
```

Comment: In case of M1, need not to uncomment "platform :ios,~~~", and just installing "arch -x86_64 pod install" resolved this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In Flutter project, I Also faced with this issue. Fixed by updating flutter and cocoa pods to the latest version.

Solution:-

- flutter clean
- rm -Rf ios/Pods
- rm -Rf ios/.symlinks
- rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
- rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
- cd ios
- pod install
- cd ..
- flutter build ios

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't remove everything inside `Podfile`, just Uncomment this line:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
```

from `ios/Podfile`

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer is uncomment second line of Podfile and change the iOS version to 10 like this. Note that the very next following Xcode build will take a bit more time than usual. I don't know why...

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
```

[image]

Comment: because it runs pod install again

Answer (score 1):

#### In side the Podfile

Specifying the platform version on your plaform

Remove the  # platform :ios, '9.0'

```
# platform :ios, '9.0' ( comment note)
```

Write it like these

```
platform :ios, '13.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

platform :ios, '9.0' is working...I simply removed # this

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because of an old project which I didn't run for like 6 months.

I just created a new Flutter project using this command
`flutter create -i swift -a kotlin project_name`

And moved the `ios` folder to my project, run it and it works!

Answer (score 0):

I have got this **error** many times while **running flutter firebase project**.
Simple solution is:
Replace:

`# platform :ios, '9.0'` with `platform :ios, '9.0'`

Actually **#** make it **commented** so we are just **uncommenting** it.

Answer (score 0):

cd iOS
run the following -

pod deintegrate --verbose
sudo gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.5

sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
arch -x86_64 pod install

Answer (score -1):

You have to remove # symbol from

- cd ios
- open podfile

and remove # symbol and save this file

## #platform :ios, '9.0'.

Then write the command pod install in your terminal.

Answer (score -1):

To solve this :
open your pod file in Andriod Studio --> ios--> Podfile then you will see at the top of the file a commented out example:

## platform :ios, '9.0'

uncomment this line and re-run the app to see if it works. If it's still not working then change the version to match your minimum requirement. I've set mine to iOS 12 as one of my dependencies required this.